# jQueryUI - moving draggable back to original position, even after dropping in droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a draggable element that I am dragging into one of various droppable areas. However, I want the draggable item to *always* return to its original position, even if it was dragged into a droppable area (the droppable areas handle their own events when the draggable is dropped onto them). Is there a way to do this?

I notice that returning true or false from the stop() function in draggable affects both its return to original position as well as whether or not it triggers the droppable's drop() function. Is there a way to handle these separately?

Comment: What if you returned false from the drop event on the droppable element?

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect anything. Adding that to the end of stop() for the draggable only makes the draggable immovable after the call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's kinda a hack but when you have

```
$('yourelement').draggable({revert:true});
```

will revert it no matter if it drops or not.  And it will still fire the drop event on the droppable element.

Comment: I don't think this is a 'hack'. It's how it's done in jQuery example: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#revert

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your droppables to accept other elements? If not, you can set the 'accept' option of the droppable to 'false'

```
$('.foo').droppable('option','accept',false);
```

Comment: This works for returning the draggable, but it is not calling drop() after that for obvious reasons. Is there a way to get around that?